# Ajex: The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Hi guys I got error like this after an Ajax call in button click event.

[image]

what can do? please help resolve my problem.

Comment: I guess you need to post your code first. Moreover don't ask people to resolve your problem, they can only help you move in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.